# A topological group is embeddble in a product of a family of second-countable topological groups if and only if it is $\omega$-narrow

Tags: topological-groups

How to prove the following property: a topological group is topologically isomorphic to a subgroup of the product of some family of second-countable topological groups if and only if it is ω-narrow

Comment: You might want to include a definition of "$\omega$-narrow" and perhaps provide some reasoning why you think this result is true. (For example, if you have read it somewhere, include the reference.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a result of my first supervisor Igor Y. Guran. Its proof it rather long and can be found, for instance, in a book “Topological groups and related structures” by his supervisor Alexander V. Arhangel'skii and co-student Mikhail G. Tkachenko (Atlantis Press, Paris; World Sci. Publ., NJ, 2008), where this results is formulated as [Theorem 3.4.23](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=B785AETmFKEC&pg=PA169&hl=ru&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).